# How to loop through multiple pages of blockfrost api in Javascript

Tags: api, blockfrost, javascript

I'm trying to count the assets at a blockfrost api endpoint. It only shows 100 items on a page though. How do you loop through all the pages and extract the asset count? Thanks for any help.

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = 'https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/accounts/stake1';
    
    const PAGE_SIZE = 100 /* 100 is the max Blockfrost page size */
    const stake_address = 'stake1'; 

    Http.open(method, url, true);
    Http.setRequestHeader('project_id', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    Http.send();
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (e.currentTarget.readyState == 4 && e.currentTarget.status == 200 && e.currentTarget.responseText != '') {
async function count_assets() {
let total = 0;
try {
                let total = 0;
                let assets = [];

do {
    assets = Http.responseText; 
    total += assets.length;
    page++;
    } while (assets.length == page);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
}
return total;
}

count_assets(stake_address).then(assets => {
console.log(stake_address, 'assets:', assets);
});
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the "Assets associated with the account addresses" endpoint. You can add query params to the request as per [specification](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D%7E1addresses%7E1assets/get).

E.g. to get 100 items on page 3: [/accounts/{stake_address}/addresses/assets?count=100&page=3](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Accounts/paths/%7E1accounts%7E1%7Bstake_address%7D%7E1addresses%7E1assets/get)

Now simply create a loop that increments the `page` query param until you don't get 100 items in the response.